# stopping and starting app in Xcode restores deleted CoreData items

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an iOS app that used Core Data in its main view controller (`MasterViewController`).  When I delete an item in the `MasterViewController` that change is reflected immediately in the table view controller however if I press stop on Xcode and then press play (command R) to start the app up again, the deleted item appears back in the list. However, if I delete the item and close the app and reopen it (without pressing start and stop on Xcode) the deleted item remains deleted. Why does pressing stop and start on Xcode reinsert the deleted item into the list? Note, I am cleaning the project. Note 2, I am testing the app on my device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you press "Stop" it kills the app without letting it shutdown cleanly. That means you never save your database. You need to make sure a save happens before quitting if you want it to persist.

Comment: ok, thanks, so this is just something that will happen in development and it's not relevant to how the app will behave on a device that's not linked to xCode

Comment: @Leahcim Saving only when app is going to background is bad idea - your app may crash and users will lost all changes in their databases. Save you data periodically or after any major change in data.

Comment: If your app is setup to save when going to the background you can do Cmd-Shift-H, which will bring you to the home screen in the simulator. Then you can Stop in Xcode.